# Disabling authentication in Passive STS WSO2 Identity Server

Tags: authentication, wso2

due at issue (https://wso2.org/jira/browse/CARBON-12174) I would disable authentication for Passive STS in WSO2 Carbon Identity Server 3.2.3.

How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible uninstall this feature using the feature manager available in WSO2 Identity Server.

- Go to 'Configure' -> 'Features' menu.
- Select the 'Installed Features' tab which will list down the installed features.
- Select the 'Passive STS' feature and click 'Uninstall'. This will start a wizard with a couple of steps.
- Restart the server.

This will remove the Passive STS features and users will not be able to connect to PassiveSTS to retrieve tokens.

P.S. - If you go to STS configuration page, you will still notice a "Passive STS Configuration" link which will lead to an empty page. But this is not a critical issue because the management console related activities are available only for administrative users.

Also this bug has been already fixed in the trunk and it will be available in the next release.

Hope this helps.

- Thilina

Comment: You are misunderstood. I would like to disable only the  authentication not the Passive STS feature. How can I skip the authentication and  retrieve the username of the logged user from SSO session  in PassiveSTS.java? Thanks for all

Comment: At the moment, it is not possible to change authentication mode in Passive STS. This might be a useful feature to add to the product.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. How to access at the trunk source for merging the the fix with public source? You can contact me to email o for further IM contacs. Thanks very much.